# Error during event typing from ReactQuery using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I use React Query to work with async requests in a React application, and I ran into the problem of typing the refetch method from the React Query library.

Component.tsx:

```
// Here is how useQuery defined in component
...
    const { data: notes = [], isLoading, isError, refetch } = useQuery<INotesList[]>(
        'notes',
        fetchNotes,
        {retry: 1, refetchOnWindowFocus: false, keepPreviousData: true})
...
// Usage of refetch on button by click event
     <button
                onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => refetch(e)}>
                Retry
    </button>
```

But, the typing that was used above does not work correctly, because in my opinion it is necessary to pass to the refetch method an event that is processed by this button, but this option is not possible, when I try, I get an error.

> TS2559: Type 'MouseEvent ' has no properties in common with type
> 'RefetchOptions & RefetchQueryFilters '.

If I don't add type to the event and pass it as

```
onClick={refetch}
```

everything works correctly, but this section of code remains without explicit typing.
Is it possible to add type to this kind of event in general?
Thank you for all answers in advance!

Comment: the `refetch` function doesn't take the mouse event as the argument. It does have one argument, but that is not what you are looking for. Why do you want to give explicit types there? It looks like TS is able to infer the types on its own.

Comment: @nullptr yes i understand you, but when i pass it like `onClick={refetch}` it underlines me this line (marking as an error) it is just ESlint issues?

Comment: why did you say everything works correctly if there is an error? if the error is there then call it like `onClick={() => refetch}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @nullptr, issue was solved: `onClick={() => refetch}`